# How can I call a superclass method like it was defined on the derived class?

Tags: javascript, class, extends, superclass

I have these classes:

```js
class Control {
  get code() {
    return 3;
  }
  getCodeChain() {
    var result = [this.code];
    if (super.getCodeChain) {
      result = result.concat(super.getCodeChain());
    }
    return result;
  }
}

class SubControl extends Control {
  get code() {
    return 2;
  }
}

class AnotherControl extends SubControl {
  get code() {
    return 1;
  }
}

console.log((new AnotherControl()).getCodeChain()); // prints 1
```

When I call `getCodeChain` on `AnotherControl` instance, it goes all the way up to Control context, so the recursion ignores `AnotherControl` and SubControl contexts.

I need to get the `CodeChain`, but I don't want/can implement the `getCodeChain()` method in all subclasses. The results I expect is [1,2,3].

How can I call a superclass method like it was defined on the derived class?

Comment: Defining `getCodeChain()` in the subclasses wouldn't solve the problem. You'll get `[1, 1, 1]` since it will still call the actual class's getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the prototype chain using `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```js
class Control {
    get code() { return 3; }
    getCodeChain() {
        const result = [];
        for (let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this); Object.hasOwn(proto, "code"); proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)) {
            result.push(proto.code);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class SubControl extends Control {
    get code() { return 2; }
}

class AnotherControl extends SubControl {
    get code() { return 1; }
}

console.log((new AnotherControl()).getCodeChain()); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: so, no use of `super`

Comment: Indeed, no use of `super`. See [documentation on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super): *"the reference of `super` is determined by the class or object literal `super` was declared in, not the object the method is called on"*

Comment: This answer is correct. The only observation is that it stops the chain if a subclass dont have the "code" property but the superclasses above have. So, the stop condition must be hasOwn(proto, "getCodeChain").

Comment: @WolfgangAmadeus, I see what you are getting at, but then you cannot get an array like the asker is looking for, so we must assume `code` is defined at every step of the chain. Secondly, that proposed stop condition would then need to still get that last step included (not excluded).

Answer (score 0):

The `super` keyword works only in the overridden method. And even then, it calls the super method on the current instance (`this`), so accessing an other property (`.code`) will again resolve that on the subclass.

What you really want is more like

```js
class Control {
  get codeChain() {
    return [3];
  }
}

class SubControl extends Control {
  get codeChain() {
    return [2, ...super.codeChain];
  }
}

class AnotherControl extends SubControl {
  get codeChain() {
    return [1, ...super.codeChain];
  }
}

console.log((new AnotherControl()).codeChain); // prints [1, 2, 3]
```