# JavaScript: How to call STATIC method on superclass but the method isnot defined on the derivated class?

Tags: javascript, static, superclass

I have these classes:

```js
class Control {

  static Code = 3;

  static GetCodeChain() {
    var result = [];
    result.push(this.Code);
    if (super.GetCodeChain) {
      result = result.concat(super.GetCodeChain());
    }
    return result;
  }
}

class SubControl extends Control {
  static Code = 2;
}

class AnotherControl extends SubControl {
  static Code = 1;
}

console.log(AnotherControl.GetCodeChain()); // prints 1, but I want [1,2,3]
```

I cannot write the methods on the subclasses.

How to call the STATIC method on the superclass properly?

Comment: A static property does not exist on an instance

Comment: Static properties are dependent on the class of the instance, not the class of the method that references it.

Comment: There is only one `GetCodeChain` on  `Control`. Subclasses don't copy the static methods.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74007846/1048572). Static properties work exactly in the same way as instance properties in regard to `super`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```js
    class Control {

        static Code = 3;

        static GetCodeChain() {
            var result = [];
            for (var proto = this; proto; proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)) {
                if (proto.Code) { result.push(proto.Code);}
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    class SubControl extends Control {
        static Code = 2;
    }

    class AnotherControl extends SubControl {
        static Code = 1;
    }

    console.log(AnotherControl.GetCodeChain()); //prints [1,2,3]
```

Using "Object.getPrototypeOf(this)" I can access the superclass even on an static context. On this context, "this" is the derivated class itself. No instances are involved on this solution.